# Connect a keyboard to my laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, keyboard

I want to add a PS2 keyboard to my laptop running Windows 7 64 bit using a PS2 to USB converter, but I couldn't get it to work and there are no related configuration options in the BIOS screens.

But when I connect the keyboard to laptop nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: The obvious question, have you restarted your Laptop after doing this?

Comment: Yes U also restarted the laptop.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the adapter even works?  Try it on another machine.

Comment: I don't like an USB port as a KB-/ mouseport. Am I a dissident?

Comment: Please don't post your question multiple times. If you need to add more information to your question, use the edit link under your original post.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you have a signal **convertor** rather than an **adapter**?

http://www.clickykeyboards.com/index.cfm/fa/items.main/parentcat/11298/subcatid/0/id/124184 explains the difference.

Question: My cheap ps/2-USB green or purple adapter is not auto-detected by Windows plug and play and I can’t get it to work. Where can I download the drivers?

Answer: The vast majority of commonly available ps2 to USB converters are simple passive ADAPTERS that simply change the plug shape to match the outlet. These ADAPTERS only function to connect the ps/2 wires to the approximate USB wires. Simple ps/2 to USB adapters do not use specific software drivers.

In general, most users having trouble connecting their keyboard to newer computers are looking for a ps/2 to USB signal CONVERTER. These devices use an integrated circuit (pre-programmed chip) to actively translate the ps/2 keyboard signal and convert it into a USB keyboard signal.

This allows the vintage ps/2 keyboard to be automatically recognized by the operating system as if it were a standard, modern USB keyboard. A well-designed active ps/2 to USB converter will use the built-in operating system drivers for a USB keyboard (for example in Microsoft Windows XP, kbdclass.sys and kbdhid.sys).

Comment: Ooh, good point.  If it's an old enough keyboard it probably isn't putting out a compatible signal.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

This is a very common adapter and when USB started to become widespread, pretty much all micr came with an adapter.

They are very cheap and your best bet is probably eBay unless you have a cheap computer shop near by.

[image]

Comment: Please bear in mind that the keyboard has to support this adapter for it to work. These adapters are just pass-through connectors that change the pin orientation, but the keyboard has to support auto-detection of the protocol it's using. If the keyboard originally came with one of these and you lost it, then it'll work. If it didn't... it might work. Maybe.

Comment: @Darth Android... Do you have any sources? I have never heard of this and have used cheap keyboards without problems... Interested to read up!

Comment: Based upon your answer and other answers [here](http://superuser.com/q/189465/19841). Unless you are talking about a different device than the ones mentioned in that question, I imagine the same information is still valid. If you are talking about a different device (one that *has* internal circuitry and actually converts the PS/2 signals into USB signals), then you should provide some way to identify this and clarify your answer. :)

Comment: @WilliamHilsum I can confirm that such an adapter did not work for me with an old brand-less keyboard included with an old PC (256MB RAM). Another report on http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52706/8250

Answer (score 5):

[image: PS/2 to USB Adapter]

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSJFJS) adapter on Amazon has a chip in it that will take even your old non-USB compatible keyboards and allow them to work over USB.