# PS2 to USB adapter for keyboard

Tags: usb, ps2, ps2-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect a keyboard to my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/309637/connect-a-keyboard-to-my-laptop)

Is it possible to connect PS2 keyboard using USB port to computer via adapter or converter ?

Comment: No need to repost the exact same question: http://superuser.com/questions/309637/connect-a-keyboard-to-my-laptop