# ps2 keyboard to usb laptop with win 10

Tags: usb, ps2

OK, here is my problem . I wanted to use my old "Microsoft natural multimedia keyboard 1.0A (PS/2 style)" with my laptop (Toshiba Satellite c75d-b7304) that runs "win 10 home", but my laptop doesn't have PS/2 port just usb's. So I got a "PS/2 to USB Adapter" ( made by Generic, ASIN B001E6DTL6), but all that happens is keyboard lights up and if I hit any keys is " USB device not recognized " . not shore what to do ? fyi if i hit num lock key it will light up or off same with caps key

Comment: More than likely that adapter is just a pass thru adapter, you will need a signal converter instead.....https://superuser.com/questions/309637/connect-a-keyboard-to-my-laptop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect a keyboard to my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/309637/connect-a-keyboard-to-my-laptop)