# Is Using USB Female to PS/2 Male passive convertor Hot-Pluggable/swapable?

Tags: desktop-computer, peripherals

I have a USB keyboard plugged into the computer PS/2 port using a USB female to PS/2 male passive converter. I'd like to know if it's safe to unplug and plug into the USB section of the converter without causing any damage to the PC, while the PC is running.

Comment: The USB connectors are designed for hot-plugging.  If the converted is really *"passive"*, then you have a "smart" keyboard that detects the host connection.  See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272716/how-to-make-your-own-ps-2-to-usb-convertor-for-old-keyboards

Comment: To research: [this](https://superuser.com/q/189465/432690) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/172420/432690).

Answer (score 1):

PS/2 is not hot pluggable , i think it would be recommended to shutdown when changing devices on a passive adapter.

Comment: Correct.  Well, actually, PS/2 is often hot pluggable in that trying a hot swap will often work.  But it does violate specs.  And usually causes no problem whatsoever.  But if it does cause a problem, the likely problem could be damage to the PS/2 port (so "fixing" that would be replacing the motherboard).